# JavaFX: Difference between action event triggered via context menu and accelerators

Tags: javafx

I have a situation where a `ContextMenu` is set for a `TableView` and the `TableView` is set as user data for the context menu, an event handler for the `ActionEvent` is registered for the `MenuItem`s.

**UPDATE 1:** *Minimal Reproducible Example*

```
package org.example.tableview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class TableViewExample extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        PersonTable personTable1 = new PersonTable(Arrays.asList(new Person("Max", "Muster"), new Person("John", "Doe")));
        Tab tab1 = new Tab("Tab 1");
        tab1.setContent(personTable1);

        PersonTable personTable2 = new PersonTable(Arrays.asList(new Person("Petar", "Petrović"), new Person("Jane", "Q")));
        Tab tab2 = new Tab("Tab 2");
        tab2.setContent(personTable2);

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(tab1, tab2);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    static class Person {
        final String givenName;
        final String surname;

        Person(String givenName, String surname) {
            this.givenName = givenName;
            this.surname = surname;
        }
    }

    static class PersonTable extends TableView<Person> {
        TableColumn<Person, String> columnGivenName = new TableColumn<>("Given name");
        TableColumn<Person, String> surname = new TableColumn<>("Surname");

        PersonTable(List<Person> persons) {
            columnGivenName.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().givenName));
            surname.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().surname));

            getColumns().addAll(columnGivenName, surname);
            getItems().addAll(persons);
            setContextMenu(new ContextMenuPersonTable(this));
        }
    }

    static class ContextMenuPersonTable extends ContextMenu {
        MenuItem menuItemAlertSurname = new MenuItem("Alert Surname");

        ContextMenuPersonTable(PersonTable table) {
            setUserData(table);

            menuItemAlertSurname.setAccelerator(KeyCombination.keyCombination("CTRL+SHIFT+S"));
            menuItemAlertSurname.setOnAction(TableViewExample::handleAlertAction);
            getItems().add(menuItemAlertSurname);
        }
    }

    static void handleAlertAction(ActionEvent event) {
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem) event.getSource();
        ContextMenu contextMenu = menuItem.getParentPopup();
        PersonTable table = (PersonTable) contextMenu.getUserData();
        TableView.TableViewSelectionModel<Person> selectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
        Person selectedItem = selectionModel.getSelectedItem();

        if (selectedItem != null) {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText(">>> " + selectedItem.surname);
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
    }
}
```

While working on the MRE I found out that the problem must be connected with the `TabView` and the number of `Tab`s: If there is only one tab the accelerator works perfectly fine. If there is more then one tab it only works fine on the second tab. The context menu works always.

**UPDATE 2:** I think the problem has to do with the fact that the same X is used for `MenuItem`s in several `ContextMenu`s. But to me that sounds like a common pattern. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: @kleopatra I did not manage to create an MRE, but I can reproduce it in my code base every time. Do you have any idea if there could be a difference in the way the selection model works?

Comment: that's a clear indication of something being wrong in your code. Nothing to do but trying harder - you _must_ find an example demonstrating the problem or ideally, the reason for the problem itself :)

Comment: @kleopatra Maybe one more thing to add: I registered _InvalidationListener_ to the `selectedItemProperty` of the `TableView`. If I select the different rows the event is triggered, when I use the KeyCombination it is not. So I don't understand why the item would be empty.

Comment: We won't be able to help much without a [mre] demonstrating the problem. The help page gives some strategies on how to create such an example. If you're unable to create a minimal example then that's a good indication the source of the problem is located somewhere in the code you haven't considered yet.

Comment: @kleopatra  After all, I managed to build an MRE.

Comment: your analysis is correct: only a single target per key is supported, multiple registrations for the same key simply replace the last. If you target might change, you have to implement it yourself. There are several options, f.i have a single entry point that distributes to the target based on some logic, or change the registration as appropriate (in this particular case, you might listen listen do so in a listener to the selected tab)

Comment: an aside (which might not apply to your real code, after all this is an example :) controls are not meant to be extended - instead they should be configured as needed.

Comment: not specific for fx8

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for your help! But if I don't extend the control, how can I use a custom TableView, for example? And what is the `fx:root` for if not for exactly this case?

Comment: sure you extend, both TableView and ContextMenu :) Don't, instead configure (not using fxml often, but probably a case for fx:include or similar)

Comment: @kleopatra I think Oracle does it my way, extending existing controls: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/custom_control.htm

Comment: repeating: don't extend if you can achieve the same by configuration! That's an example of how-to use a custom control (which _could_ be something reasonable == add functionality that's not supported, f.i. see any of the advanced or entirely new controls in ControlsFX) not more and not less. You might want to read an arbitrary tutorial about object-oriented design, if you don't want to take my word for it (which is perfectly okay :)

Comment: @kleopatra Ah, now I get your point :-) My actual implementation adds a new function to the control. There I just tried to replicate the structure. My original application is in Scala and I 'translated' it into Jave to make it easier for people to help.